# How to authorise Azure logic app api end point

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

Im creating a simple azure logic app to make a get request to api endpoint. How do I pass the access token to authorize?

I’m requesting another api from Logic app.

Comment: hope this[1] is the answer that you looking for [1] https://medium.com/@GAMACY/how-to-pass-a-bearer-token-using-azure-logic-apps-b90d597ddce7

Comment: Thats exactly what I was after. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here are the ways that you can **secure access**

- **[Generate shared access signatures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-securing-a-logic-app#sas)**
- **[Restrict incoming IP addresses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-securing-a-logic-app#restrict-incoming-ip-addresses)**
- **[Add Azure Active Directory, OAuth, or other security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-securing-a-logic-app#add-authentication)**

Comment: I’m requesting an api from the Logic app. Not calling the logic app from api.